# After upgrading to 19.10 can't read USB drives

Tags: 19.10

I just upgraded my desktop from 19.04 to 19.10 and the USB auto-mount stopped working.

Whenever I insert a USB disk I can see the automount working (The USB Key icon shows up with a notification) but when I try to open it with the file explorer (Files) I get a message saying I don't have permissions. The message is "This location cannot be displayed" and "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of..."

The problem might be that the /media user dir is being created with wrong permissions:

```
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 27 10:34 /media/ferdez/
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Fernando

Comment: Try with `sudo chgrp "$USER" /media/"$USER"`. If it is a disk that you intend to use often, it is a good alternative to have an entry for it in `/etc/fstab`, and depending of file system, you should treat it differently. What file systems are there in the USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: just remove /media/user folder and next time it will create with the same permissions but now it works. Would like to know why, though...

Fernando