# After upgrading my distribution, I didn't have permissions to access any of my USB drives. How to fix?

Tags: upgrade, usb, permissions

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. After upgrading, I would try to use a thumb drive or try to connect my backup hard drive, and I would get back an error box that said I didn't have the permissions necessary to view the contents. I didn't know what was going on the first time and I just reformatted the thumb drive after moving the contents to my phone, but this didn't do anything. When I came back to the problem today, when trying to do a hard backup, I couldn't let it linger any longer, so I went to the forums looking for answers...

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622101/552611) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, and it resolved my problems (there were similar solutions list [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184157/after-upgrading-to-19-10-cant-read-usb-drives), but there was not much explanation of the underlying problem or how to test if that in fact was the problem, so I preferred the first solution, which I'm quoting and paraphrasing here. "[T]he problem wasn't permissions to read the path to the device itself, but to the /media/[user] directory. Probably some problem caused by multiple dist-upgrades." To confirm that's in fact the issue, run the following in terminal `ls /media/[user]`. For me, confirmation looked like l`s: cannot access '/media/[user]': No such file or directory`. So then, to get back ownership of the directory, I ran `sudo chown [user] /media/[user]`. That worked for me.